# MS SQL Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Выполняю следующий простой запрос:

```
      WITH tt1 AS(
        SELECT CASE WHEN try_cast(QuestionDetailValue as int) IS NULL THEN N'Bad' ELSE N'Ok' END AS TryCast
        FROM vw.Rates)
SELECT TryCast 
FROM tt1
--WHERE TryCast = N'Bad'
```

Результатом выполнения данного запроса является только ответ 'Ok', что говорит о том, что в столбце QuestionDetailValue содержатся только числовые значения. Также, я пробовал достать DISTINCT QuestionDetailValue. Результатом являются числа от 0 до 10. И это правильно.

Но как только я раскомментирую фильтр WHERE и попробую отфильтровать, скажем, значения >= 9, выскакивает ошибка:

"Сообщение 245, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 225
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int."

И что бы я ни делал, я не могу её пропустить. Я пробовал TRY_CAST, TRY_CONVERT, CASE WHEN, CAST, CONVERT и прочее. Но я не могу никаким известным мне способом эту ошибку обойти.

И что самое главное - я не могу поймать строчку с этой ошибкой. Её просто нет. Фильтр по этим символам выдаёт просто эту же ошибку, и всё. Соответственно, по этой же причине я не могу скинуть сюда примерный CREATE TABLE, потому что я не могу поймать эти символы.

Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: В `QuestionDetailValue` у вас та строка?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3cae46e98d934a5db7c1e1999a583d4c Откорректируйте и дайте линк на fiddle с проблемой.

Comment: Да, проблема именно в QuestionDetailValue, поскольку если я запрашиваю SELECT COUNT(QuestionDetailvalue) from tt1 where QuestionDetailValue >= 9, то опять же всплывает эта ошибка.

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос в том, как можно проигнорировать любые нечисловые значения, если известные мне методы не работают? )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующее решение.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Rates TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, QuestionDetailValue NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @Rates VALUES 
(N'10'), 
(N'');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
FROM @Rates
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (IIF(TRY_CAST(QuestionDetailValue AS INT) IS NULL, N'Bad', N'Ok'))) AS t(c)
--WHERE c = N'Bad';
```

**Результат**

```
+----+---------------------+-----+
| ID | QuestionDetailValue |  c  |
+----+---------------------+-----+
|  1 | 10                  | Ok  |
|  2 |        | Bad |
+----+---------------------+-----+
```

**После раскомментирования предложения WHERE**

```
+----+---------------------+-----+
| ID | QuestionDetailValue |  c  |
+----+---------------------+-----+
|  2 |        | Bad |
+----+---------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

> `SELECT COUNT(QuestionDetailvalue) from tt1 where QuestionDetailValue >= 9`
>
> "Сообщение 245, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 225 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int."

Вероятнее всего вам нужно использовать запрос с таким условием:

```
where try_cast(QuestionDetailValue as int) >= 9
```